# .PPSX file reader?

Tags: files, office, extensions

.ppsx is the extension of MS PowerPoint.
Is there any program which can open this file type? It is not supported by OpenOffice nor by LibreOffice. The only way I can open it is launching a Windows virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libreoffice Impress *(from version 4.1 and above)* supports to open and edit .ppsx files.

You can install it from Canonical repository executing from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-impress
```